# Backbone.history.start() issue

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying this easy code from Addy's book but I can't make it work:

```
var TodoRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
     routes: {
       "about" : "showAbout",
       "search/:query" : "searchTodos",
       "search/:query/p:page" : "searchTodos"
     },
     showAbout: function(){},
     searchTodos: function(query, page){
         var page_number = page || 1;
         console.log("Page number: " + page_number + " of the results for todos containing the wo");
        }
    });

    var myTodoRouter = new TodoRouter();

    Backbone.history.start();
```

The console returns this with an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object #<Object> is not a function backbone-min.js:1
h.extend.start backbone-min.js:1
(anonymous function)
```

If I comment out Backbone.history.start() there's no error (neither the "app" behaves the way it is supposed to behave).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [SOLVED] the JS files (JQuery, Underscore and Backbone were added to HTML in the wrong order. The right order for me was: JQuery, Underscore, Backbone, MyOwnJSFiles. Thanks anyone for reading, hope this helps.

Comment: provide this comment as an answer and mark it solved please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] the JS files (JQuery, Underscore and Backbone were added to HTML in the wrong order. The right order for me was: JQuery, Underscore, Backbone, MyOwnJSFiles. Thanks anyone for reading, hope this helps